MyListing Theme: Move Category Content to Bottom of the Listicles
I'm trying to move category description to bottom of the content, by using below code.
remove_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description', 'woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description', 100 );

Unfortunately, above code is not supporting to the theme.
I can see the content right to the page. But i'm unable to see the content below of the Listings.
remove_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description', 'woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description', 100 );

Unfortunately, above code is not supporting to the theme.enter image description here
I want to add Content after pagination option
Reference content is below.
Reference content on how it should look after the pagination
Currently it's showing on this place
